# Seleccionar mediante sql siempre el último día 20

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Mi intencion es poder seleccionar apartir de una consulta todos los registros siempre apartir del ultimo dia 20.
es decir:

```
SELECT * FROM asistencia 
         where id=$Id 
         and fecha > '2018-07-20'
```

donde enlugar de 2018-07-20 sea un valor que haga referencia al ultimo dia 20 como X.
 
si estamos a 2018-07-31 , X = 2018-07-20
si estamos a 2018-07-19 , X = 2018-06-20

actual mente e llegado a usar :

```
fecha > Convert(datetime, DateAdd(month, -1, Convert(date, GetDate(),20)))
```

que trae mis registros apartir del dia 20 del mes pasado (lo que esta mal ya que podemos estar a 21 y me mostraia el registro del mes pasado)

agradesco mucho de antemano, esto es para un querry para usar en php y mostrarlo en una tabla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

puedes armar el query desde PHP

```
$now = new \DateTime('now');
$anio = (int)$now->format('Y');
$mes = (int)$now->format('m');
$dia = (int)$now->format('d');

$dia <= 20 ? $mes -= 1 : $mes;
$fecha = "$anio-$mes-20";
$query = "SELECT * FROM asistencia 
     where id=$Id 
     and fecha > '$fecha'";
```

Comment: Hola! muchas gracias, este es un problema que insisti mucho (ya me estava rindiendo y resignado a cambiar la fecha cada mes manual mente xD ) pero vi que mucha gente a tenido el mismo problema . tu respuesta es increible y simple muchas gracias . funciono muy bien !!!

Answer (score 1):

Dado que estás usando SQL Server, también hay una posibilidad de obtener el día `X` del mes anterior mediante la función `EOMONTH` (SQL Server 2012+) u otra consulta alternativa para versiones de SQL Server 2008 -.

Veamos ambas posibilidades:

### Con `EOMONTH` (SQL Server 2012+)

Si hoy, 1º de agosto ejecutas esta consulta:

```
Select DATEADD(DAY, 20, EOMONTH(GETDATE(),-2)) day_20;
```

El resultado sería:

```
day_20
---------------------------
20.07.2018 00:00:00
```

---

### SQL Server 2008 -

Si tu versión de SQL Server es inferior a 2012, puedes intentar algo como esto:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,19,DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,@date)-1,0)) day_20;
```

El resultado sería:

```
day_20
---------------------------
20.07.2018 00:00:00
```

---

### Prueba de concepto

Aquí puedes ver una <kbd>**[DEMOSTRACIÓN](http://rextester.com/DOUW32875)**</kbd> y hacer pruebas de concepto.

---

### Enlaces:

- [`EOMONTH` en la documentación de Transact-SQL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
- [Equivalente de `EOMONTH` en SQL Server 2008 -](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/samlester/2013/09/23/eomonth-equivalent-in-sql-server-2008-r2-and-below/)

Comment: tarde un poco pero ya lo pude comprobar, muchas gracias funciona igual pero se ve mejor xD mas dijerible . SQL server me a causado muchas sorpresas que me an detenido costante mente . y para bien o para mal no es ido el unoco te agradesco mucho tu aprote ! :)